# A condition equivalent to orthogonality

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

Prove that in any [inner product space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space): $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal if and only if $||x+\alpha y||\ge ||x||$ for every scalar $\alpha$.

Comment: Write the definitions in the questions please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$||x+\alpha y||^2=\langle x+\alpha y,x+\alpha y \rangle=
||x||^2+|\alpha|^2||y||^2+\bar{\alpha} \langle x, y \rangle+\alpha \langle y, x \rangle.$$

Show that if $\langle x, y \rangle\neq 0$ there is $\alpha $ such that this expresion is smaller than $||x||$.

Clearly, if $\langle x, y \rangle= 0$ then 
$$||x+\alpha y||^2=||x||^2+|\alpha|^2||y||^2\geq ||x||^2$$

Comment: This is getting embarrassing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\alpha = -(x,y)/(y,y)$, assuming $y \ne 0$. Then, by assumption,
$$
    \|x\|^{2} \le \left\|x-\frac{(x,y)}{(y,y)}y\right\|^{2}
$$ 
Using the Pythagorean Theorem:
$$
    \left\|\left(x-\frac{(x,y)}{(y,y)}y\right)+\frac{(x,y)}{(y,y)}y\right\|^{2} \le \left\|x-\frac{(x,y)}{(y,y)}y\right\|^{2} \\
   \left\|x-\frac{(x,y)}{(y,y)}y\right\|^{2}+\left\|\frac{(x,y)}{(y,y)}y\right\|^{2} \le
   \left\|x-\frac{(x,y)}{(y,y)}y\right\|^{2}
$$
Hence $|(x,y)|=0$.

Comment: Sir , I can't understand what do you mean ? I'm so sorry but could you explain to me , please ?

Comment: There's nothing there except to realize $\left(x-\frac{(x,y)}{(y,y)}y\right)$ is orthogonal to $y$. The conclusion is that $\|(x,y)y\|=0$ so that $|(x,y)|=0$.